# re_path unresolved regex (\d[1,2])

Tags: python, django, path, python-re

Please let me know why my regular expression cannot be resolved, I just copied and paste from one of the Django books, and tried to pass the parameter `re_path(r'^time/plus/(\d[1,2])/$', hours_ahead)`. Just tried to pass parameter additional hours to the current time.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/time/plus/2
```

then I got the page not found (404) error. The current path, time/plus/2, didn't match any of these.

I don't understand what is the issue here. please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it is because this is wrong regular expression if you need only one and two number like this so there is not point of specifying like this

```
case 1:
only 1 and 2 is accept
want:time/plus/2/ --pass
want:time/plus/1/ --pass
want:time/plus/3/ --fail
regex: r'^time/plus/[1,2]/$'

case 2:
length of that is 1 or 2 
want:time/plus/2/ --single digit -pass
want:time/plus/33/ --two digit -pass
want:time/plas/333/ --three digit -fail 
regex: r'^time/plus/\d{1,2}/$'
```

Comment: Thanks Kishan, it is a great explanation.  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The PATH must finish by /
you have to write the path like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/time/plus/2/
Or you modify your regex deleting /$ at the end and your previous route http://127.0.0.1:8000/time/plus/2 could work

Answer (score -1):

There are a few problems with your regex:

```
^time/plus/(\d[1,2])/$
              ^     ^
```

1. To match one or two digits, you need to use the syntax `\d{1,2}`. `\d[1,2]` would match any digit, followed by a `1`, a comma, or a `2`.
2. Your regex requires a trailing slash which your input doesn't seem to have.

Something like

```
^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/?$
```

might work.